# Use variable in place of sequential arguments in a function

Tags: r, rlang, data.tree

I'm working with the [data.trees package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html) and the syntax to work with multiple attributes is to input them in quotes as arguments to a function, like here with print(): `print(tree,"item1","item2","item99")`. I want to be able to replace that sequence of quoted arguments with a variable so I can deal with it programmatically.

The only method I've found so far is to construct the entire function call as a string using something like `str_glue()` then feed it to `str2lang()` and `eval()`:

```
data(acme) #comes with data.trees
foo<-print(acme$IT$Outsource ,"attributes")[[2]]
foo<-gsub('(\\w+)', '"\\1"', foo)

##str2lang also works
str_glue("print(acme$IT$Outsource,{foo})") %>%
str2lang()%>%eval()
```

Is there as less involved way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```r
library(data.tree)
data(acme) #comes with data.trees
library(stringr)
foo<-print(acme$IT$Outsource ,"attributes")[[2]]
#>   levelName attributes
#> 1 Outsource    cost, p
foo <- str_split(foo, ", ", simplify = TRUE) %>% trimws()

l <- c(list(acme$IT$Outsource), as.list(foo))

do.call(print, l)
#>   levelName  cost   p
#> 1 Outsource 4e+05 0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You could even write a little function that would automate all this:

```r
library(data.tree)
data(acme)
my_print <- function(x){
  require(dplyr, quietly = TRUE)
  require(stringr, quietly = TRUE)
  sink(tempfile())
  foo <- print(x, "attributes")[[2]]
  sink()
  foo <- str_split(foo, ", ", simplify = TRUE) %>% trimws()
  
  l <- c(list(x), as.list(foo))
  do.call(print, l)
}
x <- my_print(acme$IT$Outsource)
#>   levelName  cost   p
#> 1 Outsource 4e+05 0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Looks like no matter what I need to construct the entire function in at least a two-step process, there's no one-step solution where I just drop something into the back half of the ```print()``` function. ```do.call()``` is probably more R-esque way to code this than treating things as strings. Like Lumley's fortune said: "If the answer is parse you should rethink the question".

Comment: I think that's right.   I have also been a user of `parse()`, but I'm trying to kick the habit.